# One file upload at a time in blueimp jquery upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using blueimp jquery file upload to upload files. However I want a single file to be selected at a time. How do I disable selecting multiple file selections, not meant removing multiple from input. I do not want add another file when one file is selected

Comment: What is the meaning "I donot want add another file when one file is selected" and "not meant removing multiple from input" ?

Comment: when clicking add files you can add another file.so when I already added a file I don't want to add another file by clicking add file button.I already removed multiple option in input:file.Hope you understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the element from `document` at `change` event,  using [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) or set element `style` to `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the element. By using

```
 document.getElementById("ElementID").disabled = true;
```